# Stretched image in Chrome/Chromium is normal size in Firefox and Opera (CSS / HTML)

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web dev and hope my code is adequate. I have a build in progress which displays ok in Opera and Firefox but not in Chrome. Do i need to reset the browser stylesheet? Is thatever a good idea?

www.easyrstatistics.com

is the site

but this is the code snippet: HTML

```
<div class="abouttext">
<img class="aboutimage" src="aboutus.png" width=300px height=75px alt="about us"/>
<p>Ta perum inverum si nientio reperisque pero essit repudae dolo eium faceperum nienisin nem expe nimilibus, consequis ipicidest, nosseni hicipiciendi od ut voloratum volupti nisciis simustectium ut harchilibea ulliquis aut occum alici odipsam enti tempos ad escipsant eaque</p>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.aboutimage {
    float:left;
    border-style:none;
    margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0.1em 0em;
 }

.abouttext {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
    width:22em;
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Rosser

Answer (score 0):

Use double qoutes around your height and width values, and it is just a number, the px does not have to be declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
width=300px height=75px
```

those are invalid attribute values. You want this:

```
width=300 height=75
```

or, probably better:

```
style="width: 300px; height: 75px;"
```